# Swift 2 - How to hold the ImageView when switching to different views?

Tags: xcode, swift, imageview, xcode7, viewcontroller

The functionality of my application holds an imageview when selected from the gallery or taken by camera, however when i switch to my next view and return back, the image that was in the imageview disappears. How can I hold the image in the imageview when switching views?

I am fairly new to swift, I would appreciate your help thanks.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices
import AssetsLibrary
import AVFoundation
import SystemConfiguration

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {

    var controller = UIImagePickerController()
    var assetsLibrary = ALAssetsLibrary()

    @IBOutlet weak var btnClickMe: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnClickMe1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!

    var picker:UIImagePickerController?=UIImagePickerController()
    var popover:UIPopoverController?=nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker!.delegate=self

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    @IBAction func btnImagePickerClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openCamera()

        }
        let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openGallary()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
            {
                UIAlertAction in

        }

        // Add the actions
        picker?.delegate = self
        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        // Present the controller
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: alert)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func openCamera()
    {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
        {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            openGallary()
        }
    }
    func openGallary()
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        print("picker cancel.")

    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @IBAction func btnImagePicker1Clicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openCamera()

        }
        let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
            {
                UIAlertAction in
                self.openGallary()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
            {
                UIAlertAction in

        }

        // Add the actions
        picker?.delegate = self
        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        // Present the controller
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: alert)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func openCamera1()
    {
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
        {
            picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
            self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            openGallary1()
        }
    }
    func openGallary1()
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone
        {
            self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            popover=UIPopoverController(contentViewController: picker!)
            popover!.presentPopoverFromRect(btnClickMe.frame, inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController1(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel1(picker: UIImagePickerController)
    {
        print("picker cancel.")

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear from the view controller with the imageView?

Comment: @Animal I have updated my question, you will probably see that I have two functions that are the same, my applications required two imageviews which are allocated to the same class but two separate view controllers.

Comment: Which is the next viewController in after which your image disappeared and how do you present that viewController?

Comment: "however when i switch to my next view and return back" - which is the next view and how do you present it?

Comment: @Animal the "ViewController.swift" has all the relevant code that enables the user to either take a picture or choose from the gallery, this then populates the "imageview" in that same view controller. The next view controller is the same as the previous with the same class name, and is set out the same as the previous one. The problem that i am having is that even though the image view shows the image selected from either the camera or gallery when switching to my next view and returning it gets destroyed and does not display what I had previously inputed.

Comment: @Animal The next view is the same as the previous one (ViewController.swift).

Comment: There is nowhere in this code where you present another ViewController.swift. How do you mean that you navigate to it?

Comment: @Animal I am getting rather confused here, the way I navigate to my next view controller is through "Triggered Segues" I have a button where I click on it which then allows me to switch to my next view controller. However when i return to my previous view controller the image that was populated in the image view disappears when i return. I am repeating myself again here, the class name "Viewcontroller" is the same in both view controllers when switching.

Comment: Ok. So which way is the segue presented? Modaly or is it pushed?

Comment: @Animal It is done by "Action" - "Show"

Comment: Ok. Sorry, then it's not what I thought might be the problem.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo" does it stop there when coming back from the second controller?

Comment: set a breakpoint to the viewDidLoad of your first controller. On going back to your first controller (from your next) is the breakpoint fired ?

Comment: @Animal I have tried that but the image view is still disappearing when i return to the first view controller.

Comment: @Pierre I have tried that, i get an error on the first view controller, although i bypass it so the application continues to run but the image view still disappears.

Comment: What kind of error is raised ?

Comment: @Pierre When i set the breakpoint at viewDidLoad and run the application, it stops and I get an error message and does not continue. I can't remember the error message.